# Blind Hash Signatures?

Tags: hash-signature, blind-signature, blinding

Is it possible to implement blind signatures with purely hash-based signature algorithms?

Any whitepapers, code samples, etc on the subject would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible:

[Impossibility of Blind Signatures From One-Way Permutations -  Katz, Schroder, Yerukhimovich](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/papers/blind-sigs-impos.pdf)

Comment: Would this be inclusive of things like SPHINCS+?

Answer (score 2):

Till today, there is no known construction for this. The problem is that standard hash functions do not come with the necessary algebraic properties required for blinding and unblinding.