# Post-Quantum Blind Signatures?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, blind-signature

Are there any post-quantum blind signature algorithms?  Since hash-based blind signature schemes have proven to by impossible (based on a response to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54093/blind-hash-signatures)) is this an active area of research or is it only feasible by using extraordinarily large pre-quantum algorithm keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- lattice-based blind signature scheme: [“Lattice-based Blind Signatures”](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/322.pdf) (PDF)
- MQ-based blind signature scheme: [“A Practical Multivariate Blind Signature Scheme”](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/131.pdf) (PDF)
- code-based blind signature scheme: [“A Step Towards QC Blind Signatures”](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/102.pdf) (PDF)

Answer (score 3):

This is adressed for example in [Lattice-based Blind Signatures](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/322) by Markus Rückert, 2008. I only had a quick glance, and it seems there is a construction for building blind signatures based on lattice problems.

But this isn't surprising, because lattice problems can be used for:

- building post-quantum encryption schemes, key exchange, signatures, etc.
- building fully-homomorphic encryption schemes. Such a system preserves a lot of algebraic structure (in contrast to OWFs), and it should be quite easy to use this to create blind signatures (which are often based on some semi-homomorphic property)

Comment: Are there non-lattice post-quantum schemes?  The lattice stuff looks promising, but from what I understand it is nowhere near proven to be reliable (thus the SPHINCS and other hash-based signature schemes.)  "Reliable" meaning actually quantum safe - because there has been a lot of talk that it might be susceptible to quantum algorithms if some traits people aren't sure it doesn't have are proven.